# Deploy - java application using appcfg.py

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created a google-app-engine Java project in Eclipse using Google's Eclipse plugin. I had tried to deploy my application using terminal as follows:

```
~$ appcfg.py update /home/crimson/Music/Testing5/InitialData/
```

But it shows the following error:

```
appcfg.py: command not found
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you developed a Java application using Google App Engine, you shouldn't use `appcfg.py`, that is meant for Python projects. See the [documentation of Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html) for more details on how to deploy a Java-based project. In a nutshell, you will need `appcfg.sh` if you are on Linux or Mac OS X, or `appcfg.cmd` if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux try this following step :

1. Go to your `appengine-sdk/bin`
2. type `chmod u+x appcfg.sh`
3. run this command --> `sh appcfg.sh rollback` [your app war path location]